# upper bound for the mean of logistic normal distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

Assume that ${\bf x} \in R^{K \times 1}$ is a multivariate normal distribution with mean of $\mu $ covariance matrix of $\Sigma $. I want to compute the following term.

$y_k=E_x(\frac{e^{x_k}}{\sum_{k'=1}^{K}e^{x_{k'}}})$

I know that there is no analytical solution for this. But, is there any upper bound for $y_k$?

Comment: When $\mu = 0$, $y_k = 1/K$ right?

Comment: I am not quite sure about it!

Answer (score 0):

If $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are identically distributed, then
$$E(X_1/\sum_{j=1}^n X_j) = 1/n$$
to see this, note that
$$1 = E(\sum_{j=1}^n X_j / \sum_{k=1}^n X_k ) = \sum_{j=1}^n E(X_j/\sum_{k=1}^n X_k) = nE(X_1/\sum_{j=1}^n X_j)$$
When $\mu_1 = \ldots = \mu_K$ and the $\Sigma_{ii} = \Sigma_{jj}$ for every $1 \leq i,j \leq K$, then the $e^{x_k}$ are identically distributed so you can use the above to get $y_k = 1/K$.

You might be able to get the general case by writing each normal distribution as $\sigma Z + \mu$, where $Z \sim N(0,1)$, but I'm not sure if the calculation will work out.